# Can a continuous cause have a discrete effect?

Tags: continuous-data, discrete-data

Say we have a continuous temperature as an input and a few climate categories as an output. For example, if the temperature is between `22.93` and `27.65` degrees it is `comfortable`. If it is over `27.65`, it is `uncomfortable`.

Does this sort of model automatically convert temperature into a discrete variable because the result is discrete? Or should the temperature still be treated as continuous, but won't that be illogical?

Comment: Consider an analogy:  how much arsenic a person eats.  For all practical purposes, that can be treated as a continuous cause.  The next day, the person is either dead or alive.  That's a discrete effect.

Comment: @jbowman I think in this case there would be a thousand other variables like person's health, weight, genetics, etc. If all other variables are controlled for, wouldn't there be a precise threshold of arsenic that separates the outcomes of life and death? 2 discrete inputs 2 discrete outputs? or maybe I'm being too philosophical about it...

Comment: The input / cause is how much arsenic the person eats, not how much the person needs to eat in order to die.  You are confusing the threshold with the thing being thresholded; a category mistake (https://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-category-mistake.htm).

Comment: @jbowman I think that hits the nail on the head there. Except now I'm wondering if input and cause are the same categories. Probably not at all. Because I'm sure eating above a certain threshold of arsenic would cause death. But now my intuition tells me that input would in fact be the quantity of arsenic, which is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

A continuous cause can have a discrete effect, as you've pointed out.

> Does this sort of model automatically convert temperature into a discrete variable because the result is discrete?

What do you mean by "automatically convert"? Mathematical objects such as the variables you describe don't generally have things automatically happen to them.

> Or should the temperature still be treated as continuous, but won't that be illogical?

Seems quite reasonable to me that temperature is continuous. In fact if you've defined temperature as a continuous variable, the fact that it's treated as continuous is almost tautological.

Comment: What I mean is now it would seem the temperature is either within `22.93 to 27.65` interval or above `27.65` so it can have one two values as far as the model goes. The continuity within those values now seems irrelevant, or is it still relevant within the model?

Comment: @ArthurTarasov if you are trying to answer the question "is the temperature comfortable", then yes, you only need to know whether the temperature is above or below a certain value, but that doesn't change the fact that temperature is continuous. In real life, temperature or weight or length doesn't suddenly "become" a binary variable whenever I need to test if something is above/below a threshold.

Comment: What is blowing my mind is whether it makes sense to consider a continuous variable as a valid input to a model with discrete output or whether the continuous variable has to be converted into a set of discrete values before it can become an input for a model with discrete output.

Comment: There is no rule that the "discreteness" of the input and outputs of a model must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a model. This is just recoding a variable.

Now, if you measured the temperature in a room and had a variety of subjects rate the room on a "comfortable" scale, you could then create a model where the temperature in the room predicted how comfortable subjects were in the room.